# Configure email SMTP Server on Apache2

Tags: linux, postfix, smtp, apache-2.4

For a while we decided to use another Server (VServer "B") for our Mailserver. I transfered all email accounts and mailbox from VServer "A" to VServer "B". VServer "B" runs well and the clients are getting their emails from this server. All emails that come from external SMTP-Servers are received by VServer "B".

**On VServer "A" is running:**

- apache2
- Old mailserver (postfix + dovecot)

**On VServer "B" is running:**

- New mailserver (postfix + dovecot)

**THE PROBLEM:**

I have the problem regarding to my apache2 on VServer "A". When a user uses i.e. a contact form, a PHP script sends email to the old Mailserver installed on same server. The email accounts still exist on VServer "A" because I didn't want to lose emails that come from contact forms.

At the moment I transfer the emails from VServer "A" to VServer "B" manually once a day.

**THE QUESTION**

Can someone please tell me how to configure PHP or Apache2 that emails sent from PHP by VServer "A" received by VServer "B".

---

**EDIT [SOLUTION]:**

Thank you for your Answer. But i fixed the issue by changing the postfix configuration.

**1. Changes in /etc/postfix/master.cf:**

I commended out the 2 lines which connected postfix to dovecot on Server A:

```
#dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -d ${recipient}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways you could fix this.

1. Change the SMTP setting in php.ini on the web server to use serverB rather than localhost
2. Add aliases to to the postfix config on serverA to redirect new messages to serverB for each of the local addresses you want to handle.
3. Change your PHP code/application config to use qualified addresses which deliver to serverB rather than bare user names (which is what I'm assuming you're using now).

This all assumes that you can successfully send mail from serverA to serverB. Testing that on the command line would be a sensible first step.

Comment: Where is `php.ini`?